# How to write 1 object of array in Vuex store in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component, vuex

I have a small problem
Im send axios request to the server and i get response of array
In the next step when user click of someone of this objects im need send data in the next Vue Component
But whatever I do, the first object from the list is displayed on the next component
If someone know how to solve this problem I'll be very grateful
this is my code from Vuex store

```js
    function initialState () {
    return {
        accounts: [],
        activeAccount: {},
    }
}

    async getAccounts(ctx) {
        ctx.commit('setIsLoad', true);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            getAccounts()
                .then(resp => {
                    if(resp.data.message)
                        ctx.commit('setAccounts', []);
                    else
                        ctx.commit('setAccounts', resp.data.accounts);
                        ctx.commit('setActiveAccount', resp.data.accounts[0]);
                        // ctx.commit('setActiveLs', resp.data.activeLs);
                    ctx.commit('setIsLoad', false);
                    resolve(resp.data)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    ctx.commit('setIsLoad', true);
                    reject(error)
                })
        })
    },

     selectAccount(ctx, account) {
        ctx.commit('setActiveAccount', account);
        ctx.commit('setActiveLs', account);
    },

    const mutations = {

    setAccounts(state, accounts)
    {
        state.accounts = accounts;
    },
    setActiveAccount(state, account)
    {
        state.activeAccount = account;
    },

}
```

this is my code in Vue Component

```html
    <div class="card-body">
                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush my-2" v-for="account in accounts" :key="account.ls">
                                <li class="list-group-item text-center dark-grey-text">
                                    <a @click="onClickAccountButton(account)" class="btn border btn-block black-text"><i class="fas fa-home fa-2x float-left text-primary"></i>{{account.ls}} {{account.name}} {{account.address}}</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <router-link :to="{name:'stats'}" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add New Info</router-link>
                        </div>
```

```js
    onClickAccountButton(account){
                this.selectAccount(account).then(() => {
                    this.$store.commit('account/setActiveAccount', account)
                    this.$router.push('/dashboard')
                })
                // this.$router.push('dashboard')

            },
```

Comment: show your `selectAccount` method. Also consider using actions instead of commits in your components

Comment: selectAccount(ctx, account) {
    ctx.commit('setActiveAccount', account);
    ctx.commit('setActiveLs', account);
},